# Determining Last Names in excel from a range of full names in varying formats

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Ok, I have a column of full names that are in listed in several different formats:

```
lastName/firstName
lastName, firstName
firstName lastName
firstName middleInitial lastName
firstName middleName lastName
```

I need to create a formula that extracts lastName from each one of these formats.

I have come up with the following partial formulas:

1. for determining "/", which works if cell DOES contain "/"
   `=IF(FIND("/",D2)>0,LEFT(D2,FIND("/",D2)-1)`,"Rather than displaying this message, if D2 does not contain '/' this results in the dreaded #VALUE!")
2. for determining ",", which DOES work if cell contains ","
   `=IF(FIND(",",D2)>0, LEFT(D2, FIND(",",D2)-1)`,"if D2 does not contain ',' this results in #VALUE! and not this message")

When I attempt to embed these if statements, I only get an error rather than getting a result for "/" or "," types and still do not get anything but errors for an 'else' situation. This was my attempt:

`=IF(FIND("/",D5)>0, LEFT(D5,FIND("/",D5)-1), IF(FIND(",",D5), LEFT(D5,(FIND(",",D5))-1)`, “This should be the close of the first imbedded ‘if’and this statement should populate if D5 does not contain '/' or ',' but instead... #value! ”)

I have additionally googled a solution for pulling lastName if lastName is only one word (it will not work for John St. Paul if I want St. Paul to populate):

```
IF(RIGHT(D5,LEN(D5)-FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(D2," "," ",LEN(D5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D5," ",""))))))
```

I am not 100% on this, but it spend some more time staring at it I know I could understand what it's saying, but at this time, I can't get my original function to not fail before even getting this far.

So...

If someone has a good idea how to write a single formula that will combine all three of these and if anyone has a good idea about handling the rare times I will have a two-word value for lastName I would be so thankful!

Best,

Andy

Comment: How do you recognize the lastname given the following two examples? Mr Frank Bruno and Mr Bruno Frank...

Comment: Does the order also exist  Lastname, Firstname, middlename ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to create a formula that extracts lastName from each one of these formats.

Excel is not designed for text processing, and there are better ways, but it can achieve what you seek, assuming your examples are in ColumnA starting A1 and you will copy down the following:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")),LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1),IF(LEN(A1)>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")),LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1),IF(LEN(A1)=1+LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),MID(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+2,LEN(A1)),FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))))
```

Comment: This is great! It still does not work unfortunately for someone whose last name is two words such as lastName = "St. Pierre", but this is so perfect for everything else! Thank you fo taking the time to construct this! I might be able to get away with using just this for the meantime...

Answer (score 1):

I am offering this answer as an alternative to a pure Excel based solution, which would be very verbose, difficult to maintain, and error prone.  We can fairly easily handle your problem using regex, with the following pattern:

```
^[^\s,\/]+(?: \S+)? |[,\/].*$
```

This pattern will match, in every line, all the content *except* for the last names.  Then, when doing a regex replacement, you may simply replace the match with empty string.

### Demo

Tools which can easily handle this include things like Notepad++ and most IDEs, which also have regex support.

Comment: Nice answer. This can be used in VBA using the `VBScript.RegExp` object.

Comment: This fails on two word last names

Comment: @chrisneilsen There is no way to discern `FIRST MIDDLE LAST` from `FIRST LAST1 LAST2`.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: "there is no way to discern": Correct, there is no way to detect name parts out of full name strings without using AI. And even humans may fail with this sometimes, so even AI will fail sometimes.

Comment: @AxelRichter The real problem is that the OP collected unnormalized full name data where everything is mixed together.

Comment: Hey guys thank you so much! I am not familiar with utilizing such tools though this looks like something I will have to look into in the future. Thank you Tim for the work and thank you Chris for the clarifications. I am just going to have to come up with a different way to "spot" the two last namers as they roll through.